# search in elastic search index created using a json file

Tags: json, elasticsearch, nested, parent-child

I pushed a json file ( as shown below ) to ES using the following code :

`with open('test.json','rb') as payload:
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:9200/test_nest_json/1',data=payload, verify=False, headers=headers)`

`{
    "data": [
        {
            "keyword": "abc", 
            "lists": [
                {
                    "item_val": "some_val"
                }
            ], 
            "another_key": "some_key"
        }, 
        {
            "keyword": "xyz", 
            "lists": [
                {
                    "item_val":"another_val"
                }
            ], 
            "another_key": "pqr"
        }
    ]
}`

I tried updating the mappings and used the `term` query but still it results in displaying all the indices. I am not able to query only one keyword like `"data.keyword" = "abc"` using term query.

Comment: I tried  the following `term` query: 
`{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
           "path": "data",
           "query": {
               "match": {
                  "daya.keyword": "xyz"
               }
           }
        }
    }
} `
It retrieves all the indices which is not the expected result

Comment: Can you provide `full query` instead of just body of query provided above?
Can you also update your question with more than 1 sample docs and expected result if possible!

Comment: @avr here's another sample doc :
`
{
    "students": [
        {
            "name": "abc",  
            "subject": "computer_science"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "xyz",  
            "subject": "Physics"
        }
    ]
}
`

Comment: @avr And the full query is `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 6f0d153c-d012-2ecf-6963-079fbaaf10c9" -d '{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
           "path": "student",
           "query": {
               "match": {
                  "student.name": "abc"
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
' "http://localhost:9200/test_index/_search"`
The expected output would be only that index which contains the key i have searched for.

Comment: why are you storing all student objects under one array? If it is needed then you should look @deathyr answer. Otherwise, if you store each student object as 1 document instead of array then you will achieve it simply with `match` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me :

```
es.indices.refresh(index="test-index")
with open('abc.json','rb') as payload:
json_data = json.load(payload);
leng = len(json_data["data"])
for i in range (leng):
    doc = json.dumps(json_data["data"][i]);
    res = es.index(index="sample-index", doc_type='pdf',id=str(uuid.uuid4()), body=doc)
```

I am parsing the json and extracting the array items one by one and push it to ElasticSearch.

```
{
        "keyword": "abc", 
        "lists": [
            {
                "item_val": "some_val"
            }
        ], 
        "another_key": "some_key"
},
```

Still looking for an optimised solution.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are having a problem with nested object
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html

> The reason for this cross-object matching, as discussed in Arrays of
>   Inner Objects, is that our beautifully structured JSON document is
>   flattened into a simple key-value format in the index

So the effective document stored looks like this:

```
{
  "data.keyword":            [ abc, xyz ],
  "data.another_key":        [ some_key, pqr ],
}
```

Which means the query you posted will match any document, as long as **at least one** of the nested object contains the xyz keyword. I recommend reading the link above for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did read through the link you mentioned. Going by what ElasticSearch documentation says looks like I have to change the structure of JSON that am pushing to elastic search. With the same structure I do not know how to query and extract only the matching entry. Either I have to use inner objects or push each element `{
            "keyword": "xyz", 
            "lists": [
                {
                    "item_val":"another_val"
                }
            ], 
            "another_key": "pqr"
        }` Separetely.

Comment: Did you define a mapping template for your test_index? If yes can you edit your question to include it? I would still suggest to store each document as a separate element, but if you really want to use that query and keep the object nested, you may need to map the data field as type nested instead of type object, such that each nested object is indexed as a hidden separate document.